# bwmorph(image,'clean') equivalent in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a function to clean an image in opencv which is equivalent to

```
bwmorph(image,'clean');
```

in matlab??The clean function  Remove isolated pixels (1's surrounded by 0's) according to MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Morphological operations such as eroding will work for your question, i think..

[OpenCV Erode-Dilate Example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html)

[OpenCV More Morphological Operations](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, simply using Erode-Dilate will not have the exact same effect that bwmorph(image,'clean') would. According to its [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html), clean method:

> Removes isolated pixels (individual 1s that are surrounded by 0s), such as the center pixel in this pattern.

I was unable to find an equivalent implementation, then I implemented it using the core logic shared on [this website](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/) about openCV with python.

Here's my implementation:

```
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
import numpy as np
import cv2
def bwmorphClean(image):
    (iH, iW) = image.shape[:2]
    pad = 1
    image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, pad, pad, pad, pad, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    output = np.zeros((iH, iW), dtype="float32")

    for y in np.arange(pad, iH + pad):
        for x in np.arange(pad, iW + pad):
            roi = image[y - pad:y + pad + 1, x - pad:x + pad + 1]

            if roi[0,0] == roi[1,0] == roi [2,0] == roi [0,1] == roi [0,2] == roi [1,2] == roi [2,1] == roi [2,2] == 0:
                output[y - pad, x - pad] = 0
            else:
                output[y - pad, x - pad] = roi[1,1]

    output = rescale_intensity(output, in_range=(0, 255))
    output = (output * 255).astype("uint8")

    return output
```

I'm aware you used the "c++" tag, but I do believe that by using my code as an example, you'd be able to translate it to c++ with ease.