# Implementing bwmorph(image,'thin','inf') then finding number of branchpoints in c++ using opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I would like to implement the following Matlab code for a given image in c++, which calculates the number of branch points in a medial axis skeleton representation of an image:

```
skelImg   = bwmorph(imageName, 'thin', 'inf');
branchImg = bwmorph(skelImg, 'branchpoints');
[row, column] = find(branchImg);
branchPts     = [row column];
cNumBranchPoints = length(branchPts);
```

I have seen this example: [How to implement an function equivalent to bwmorph Matlab function in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058485/how-to-implement-an-function-equivalent-to-bwmorph-matlab-function-in-opencv) which is similar in nature, although slightly different, in that I do not want to 'clean' the image, but rather 'thin' it. I also want to determine the number of *branch points*, not *end points*, as in the aforementioned example.

Anyone have an idea as to how I can do this in c++?

Best,

Ben

Comment: If by "branch" points you want to search for those points where there is a split, use a 3 x 3 pixel neighbourhood and search to see if the total number of white pixels is 4 or more.  If the count is three, this means that we are following along the skeleton.  If the count is two, then this is an end point.  Search for neighbourhoods where the total number of white pixels is 4 or more.  If that's the case, the centre of the neighbourhood is a potential branch point.

Comment: @rayryeng - thanks for your comment. Can I confirm - are white pixels those that are not part of the structure of interest? (The others being black).

Comment: White are those that belong to the skeleton.

Comment: The algorithm used by Matlab's thinning operation is described by a paper mentioned at this link:  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/433774-what-algorithm-does-matlab-rely-on-to-thinning-the-image?s_tid=prof_contriblnk

Comment: and here's some code that claims to implement the algorithm in python:  https://gist.github.com/bmabey/4dd36d9938b83742a88b6f68ac1901a6