# OpenCV Find a middle line of a contour [Python]

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

In my image processing project, I have already obtained a masked image (black-and-white image) and its contours using the `cv.findContours` function. My goal now is to create an algorithm that can draw a middle line for this contour. The masked image and its contour are shown in the following images.

**Masked image:**

[image: Masked image]

**Contour:**

[image: Contour]

In my imagination, for that contour, I would like to create a middle line which is near horizontal. I have manually marked my ideal middle line in red. Please check the following image for the red middle line that I have mentioned.

**Contour with the middle line:**

[image: Contour with middle line]

It is noticeable that my ultimate goal is to find the tip point that I have marked in yellow. If you have other ideas that can directly find the yellow tip point, please also let me know. For finding the yellow tip point, I have tried two approaches `cv.convexHull` and `cv.minAreaRect`, but the issue is the robustness. I made these two approaches worked for some images but for some other images in my dataset, they are not working very well. Therefore, I think to find the middle line might be a good approach that I can try.

Comment: You can use morphology. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058485/how-to-implement-an-function-equivalent-to-bwmorph-matlab-function-in-opencv/22060992#22060992  please. You can alse ckeck here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html

Comment: compute the rotated rectangle about the region using minAreaRect. That will give you the 4 corners and the orientation angle. You can then compute the mid-line from the 4 corners and draw a line.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for your response. I have tried `cv.minAreaRect` before asking this question. For some of the images in my dataset, the computed rectangle is not at the orientation that I desired. For instance, if this object is at the corner of the image area, the computed min-area-rect will be similar to a square, and its orientation is not accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're trying to determine the contour's center of gravity and orientation. We can easily do this using [Central Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Central_moments). More info on that [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/contour-and-area-raw-spatial-and-central-image-moments#8521).

The code below generates [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTggv.png). Is this the result you wanted?

```
# Determine contour
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_bin = (img>128).astype(np.uint8)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_bin, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Determine center of gravity and orientation using Moments
M = cv2.moments(contours[0])
center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
theta = 0.5*np.arctan2(2*M["mu11"],M["mu20"]-M["mu02"])
endx = 600 * np.cos(theta) + center[0] # linelength 600
endy = 600 * np.sin(theta) + center[1]

# Display results
plt.imshow(img_bin, cmap='gray')
plt.scatter(center[0], center[1], marker="X")
plt.plot([center[0], endx], [center[1], endy])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

> My goal right now is to create an algorithm that can draw a middle line for this contour.

If you detect the upper and lower bounds of your horizontal-lines, then you can calculate the middle-line coordinates.

For instance:

[image]

Middle-line will be:

[image]

If you change the size to the width of the image:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("contour.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]

x1_upper = h
x1_lower = 0
x2_upper = h
x2_lower = 0
y1_upper = h
y1_lower = 0
y2_upper = h
y2_lower = 0

lines = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(gray)

for cur in lines:
    x1 = cur[0][0]
    y1 = cur[0][1]
    x2 = cur[0][2]
    y2 = cur[0][3]

    # upper-bound coords
    if y1 < y1_upper and y2 < y2_upper:
        y1_upper = y1
        y2_upper = y2
        x1_upper = x1
        x2_upper = x2
    elif y1 > y1_lower and y2 > y2_lower:
        y1_lower = y1
        y2_lower = y2
        x1_lower = x1
        x2_lower = x2


print("\n\n-lower-bound-\n")
print("({}, {}) - ({}, {})".format(x1_lower, y1_lower, x2_lower, y2_lower))
print("\n\n-upper-bound-\n")
print("({}, {}) - ({}, {})".format(x1_upper, y1_upper, x2_upper, y2_upper))

cv2.line(img, (x1_lower, y1_lower), (x2_lower, y2_lower), (0, 255, 0), 5)
cv2.line(img, (x1_upper, y1_upper), (x2_upper, y2_upper), (0, 0, 255), 5)

x1_avg = int((x1_lower + x1_upper) / 2)
y1_avg = int((y1_lower + y1_upper) / 2)
x2_avg = int((x2_lower + x2_upper) / 2)
y2_avg = int((y2_lower + y2_upper) / 2)

cv2.line(img, (0, y1_avg), (w, y2_avg), (255, 0, 0), 5)

cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleive skeleton is what you are looking for.

```
import cv2
import timeit

img = cv2.imread('Ggh8d - Copy.jpg',0)
s = timeit.default_timer()
thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(img, thinningType = cv2.ximgproc.THINNING_ZHANGSUEN)
e = timeit.default_timer()
print(e-s)
cv2.imwrite("thinned1.png", thinned)
```

[image: skeleton]

if smooth the edge a little bit

[image: smooth]

[image: smooth skeleton]
Actually the line will not torch the yellow point, since the algorithm have to check distance from edges, yellow point is located on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do that by computing the centerline of the rotated bounding box about your object in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("blob_mask.jpg")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold the grayscale image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get coordinates of all non-zero pixels
# NOTE: must transpose since numpy coords are y,x and opencv uses x,y
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))

# get rotated rectangle from 
rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
box = np.int0(box)
print (box)

# get center line from box
# note points are clockwise from bottom right
x1 = (box[0][0] + box[3][0]) // 2
y1 = (box[0][1] + box[3][1]) // 2
x2 = (box[1][0] + box[2][0]) // 2
y2 = (box[1][1] + box[2][1]) // 2

# draw rotated rectangle on copy of img as result
result = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(result, [box], 0, (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.line(result, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,0,0), 2)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("blob_mask_rotrect.png", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]