# from MATLAB to C++: equivalent of bwmorph with option 'remove'

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I found a version of MATLAB `bwmorph` function for C++ with option `'endpoints'` here [How to implement an function equivalent to bwmorph Matlab function in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058485/how-to-implement-an-function-equivalent-to-bwmorph-matlab-function-in-opencv) and one for option `'clean'` here [bwmorph(image,'clean') equivalent in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132770/bwmorphimage-clean-equivalent-in-opencv) but none for option `'remove'`. Does anyone have a C++ implementation?

Comment: Recommend rewording your question. As written it's pushing up against being an off-topic request for a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `'remove'` option to `bwmorph](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html#bui7adf-1-operation):

> Removes interior pixels. This option sets a pixel to 0 if all its 4-connected neighbors are 1, thus leaving only the boundary pixels on.

You can implement this using a simple 4-connected erosion, then taking the difference between input and eroded image.

```
auto se = getStructuringElement(MORPH_CROSS, Size{3,3});
erode(in, out, se);
subtract(in, out, out);
```

Comment: great! but a 3,3 filter is not a 8-connected filter?

Comment: @volperossa: A 3x3 cross is a 4-connected filter, a 3x3 square is an 8-connected filter.